# R package: distr6

Tags: r

```
fctry=function(s){(exp(-r/a)*(k+m-s))}

set.seed(10); r<- runif(100)
set.seed(20); k<- runif(100)
set.seed(30); m<- runif(100)
a=12*c(1:100)
distr6::Distribution$sup(fctry)
```

I am trying to compute supremum of the function "fctry", however an error comes out (attempt to apply non-function).

Even if I try another function such as

```
fctry2=function(s){exp(s)-s}
distr6::Distribution$sup(fctry2)
```

This doesn't work neither. May I ask help to solve this problem? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using distr6. The error is because you are using the R6 interface incorrectly. My suggestion would be to start with the distr6 tutorials and see if that helps, I'd advise starting [here](https://alan-turing-institute.github.io/distr6/articles/webs/intro_to_r6.html).

I think you may also be using distr6 incorrectly. distr6 is for distributions and so the method you are trying is for finding the supremum of a *distribution* and not of an abstract function. Instead you may want the [optimize](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/optimize) function